# SQL query to bring months that doesn't exist in a column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to count the number of rows with respect to the month that they've written in database. My database has a column named `created_date`. you can see what i've done bellow :

```
select month(created_date) as "Month", count(created_date) as "Count" from transactions group by month(created_date)
```

what this query returns is something like this :

```
{'Month':1,'Count':10}
```

this happens because i only have one month in my database, while i need to have all months in results, including months that doesn't exist in database, like this :

```
{'Month':1,'Count':10}
{'Month':2,'Count':0}
{'Month':3,'Count':0}
{'Month':4,'Count':0}
{'Month':5,'Count':0}
{'Month':6,'Count':0}
{'Month':7,'Count':0}
{'Month':8,'Count':0}
{'Month':9,'Count':0}
{'Month':10,'Count':0}
{'Month':11,'Count':0}
{'Month':12,'Count':0}
```

how should i do it?

Comment: If appropriate, consider instead handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Comment: @Strawberry yeah, that's a good advice, i knew i can do it in application level, what i want to know is that which one is faster? doing it in application level or using join and writing query in database?

Comment: by the this all add up all transactions over all years?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could `JOIN` to a list of months so you can get a row even for months that don't exist in your table:

```
SELECT m.month,
       COUNT(t.created_date)
FROM (SELECT 1 AS month UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3
      UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6
      UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
      UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12) m
LEFT JOIN transactions t ON MONTH(t.created_date) = m.month
GROUP BY m.month
```

Comment: in this case i have `12` numbers as classes, what if we have `n` classes? assuming that `n` is a large number. am i supposed to write those classes one by one in query? is there a way to generate these numbers automatically in query?

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi If you're using MySQL prior to v8, then other than making a calendar table or numbers table, this is the only way.

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi if you get performance issues with this query as `MONTH(t.created_date) = m.month` is not *"sargable"* consider add a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) where you precalculate `MONTH(t.created_date)` and index it then you can use that column in this query..

Comment: *"really good point. Thanks for making it"* No problem i remove a other comment as it sounded it a bit to negative to this answer..  Not sure about a other approach how to make this `MONTH(t.created_date) = m.month` expression *"sargable"* and futher proof, The topicstarter could also try string manipulation with `LIKE '...%'` but MySQL 8 will disallow using `LIKE '...%'` on date/datetime datatypes...

Comment: @RaymondNijland I think you're right about the generated column being the best way.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * from
(
 SELECT 1 as month UNION ALL
 SELECT 2 as month UNION ALL
..
SELECT 12 as month 
) as months
left outer join
(
select month(created_date) as "Month", count(created_date) as "Count" from transactions group by month(created_date)
) as data
on (months.month=data.month)
ORDER BY months.month
```

Comment: in this case i have `12` numbers as classes, what if we have `n` classes? assuming that `n` is a large number. am i supposed to write those classes one by one in query? is there a way to generate these numbers automatically in query?

Comment: There absolutely is.  You just need to select from a table that contains the values you need!  If you just want a load of numbers you can select a cross product in the sub query to quickly generate loads of values.